# Database design from a json file

Tags: database, database-design

I have a json file like this

```
[
     {

       "topic": "Example1", 
       "ref": {
            "1": "Example Topic", 
            "2": "Topic"
        }, 
       "contact": [
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "corresponding": true, 
                "name": "XYZ"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "name": "ZXY"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "name": "ABC"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1, 
                    2
                ], 
                "name":"BCA"
            }
        ] , 

        "type": "Presentation"
     }, 
    {

       "topic": "Example2", 
       "ref": {
            "1": "Example Topic", 
            "2": "Topic"
        }, 
       "contact": [
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "corresponding": true, 
                "name": "XYZ"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "name": "ZXY"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1
                ], 
                "name": "ABC"
            }, 
            {
                "ref": [
                    1, 
                    2
                ], 
                "name":"BCA"
            }
        ] , 

        "type": "Poster"
     }
]
```

I created `3 Tables`Items,Reference,Contact one is

```
 Items:
    Item_ID
    topic
    type
  reference:
    ref_ID
    content
   Contact:
     ref_ID
     contact_ID
     Item_ID
     name
```

RelationShip :

```
1) Items has many references
2)Items has many Authors
3)Authors has many references
```

Now, my question is

1) Should I doing any wrong here?

2) is there any way to improve the my current implementation ?

3) Here I am confused about to implement the `corresponding`(inside the contact Array). How do I implement that in design ?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give us a meaning-ful json

Comment: Does my answer suits for you? Is wat you expected? or anything missing?

Comment: It should be noted there are databases out there, like CouchDb, that just store JSON as-is, no schema necessary. That may actually suit your use case better, depending on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your above Json., what I could infer is this normalized schema. You have 2 ref in your above Json. Could you clarify it?

Also, here a useful link for you.,  http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ Switch between viewer and Text tabs.

The actual example from your scenario is.,

```
P- Primary Key
Ref - Reference Key


Topic:
--------------------------------------------------
Topic ID (P)  | TopicName            | TypeID (Ref)
----------------------------------------------------
  0               Example1                       0
  1               Example2                       1


TopicReferences :
----------------------------
TopicID (P) | RefernceID (Ref)
--------------------------------
  0                 0
  0                 1
  1                 0
  1                 1

Reference :
------------------------------------
ReferenceID (P)  | ReferenceName 
------------------------------------
  0                 Example Topic
  1                 Topic 

Presentation Type :
--------------------------
TypeID (P) | TypeName 
--------------------------
 0           Presentation
 1           Poster

TopicContacts:
---------------------------------
TopicID  | ContactID   (Ref)
---------------------------------
   0              0
   0              1
   0              2
   0              3
   1              0
   1              1
   1              2
   1              3

Contact:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
ContactID(P)  | ContactName | IsCorresponding ( Boolean, nullable)
------------------------------------------------------------------
   0                XYZ             YES
   1                ZXY             NULL
   2                ABC             NULL
   3                BCA             NULL

ContactsReference2:
--------------------------------------------
ContactID  | Reference2ID  (Ref)
--------------------------------------------
  0                  0
  1                  0
  2                  0
  3                  0
  3                  1

Reference2:
--------------------------------------------
Reference2ID(P)  | Reference2Value (NUM)
--------------------------------------------
   0                         1
   1                         2
```